# My server cant connect to internet?

Tags: linux, centos

I'm not sure what happened to my server but Ill try to tell you what I have done before it happened and what happened after.

I tried installing OpenVPN on my server using iptables to change it up so that the gateway redirects to something else I wasnt sure what I was running which was a mistake on my part. The commands where supposed to re route the vpn users into the server instead of their own connection.

After this happened I can only use IPMI. Along with that I cannot install any software because it keeps giving me this error (Could not resolve host: URL; unknown error)
Pinging any site leads to connect: Network is unreachable, I checked my name servers and they are nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4

I apprently dont have ifconfig or ip command

eth0 doesn't exist on my dedicated server? I'm sure it was there before tried repairing it but didn't seem to re-create it or anything

I'm on CentOS 7

EDIT: Forced to only use IPMI nothing else works the thing seems like its not even connected to the internet or the DNS is broke or something not sure.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Server wont connect to the internet, it can't access anything and I can only access it through ipmi

Comment: Your comment still isn't a question.

Comment: What happens if you switch off OpenVPN?

Comment: Also "I apparently don't have ifconfig or ip command" is kind of weird - what if you call them directly with full path? Something like `/sbin/ifconfig`, `/sbin/ip`?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you changed the gateway on the connection and now it cant reach outside.  Using IPMI you need to change the gateway back to what it was originally, and try again.  IPMI is invaluable when working on networking.